# Creating Data Frame or Group Layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, group-layer

I am attempting to write some Python code which creates a blank data frame or group layer which can then be populated with other layers. I'm at a loss as to how to do this since I'm somewhat new to Python coding.

Comment: Does this answer help you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/add-a-new-group-layer-with-python-arcgis-10