# Making Grouped Layers in ModelBuilder using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, layers, group-layer

I started using ArcMap 10.4 just a few weeks ago, I've started to get a handle on the ModelBuilder however I can't seem to make the layers I export be automatically grouped.

So far this is the most time consuming part of the process and I'd rather avoid it if I can because I can put them in a folder but then have to manually drop them into my premade groups.

Someone on here mentioned that you can do this with Python but I have virtually no Python experience, is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ArcMap 10.4 is quite old and probably unsupported by ESRI. The behaviour you seek does exist in ArcGIS Pro 2.8+ although it is flaky and breaks downstream flow of logic, so personally I would not recommend you use it.

As for ArcMap 10.4, you can't group layers into group layers which are outputs of model runs purely with the tools that model builder offers. So you need to use python to create the behaviour you seek and to throw a spanner into the works arcpy is incapable of creating group layers! You need to fake it and an example of this is discussed at [Adding new group layer with ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4681).

Unless there is some overriding demand for layers to be grouped and as you say you lack python programming skills, I think this is an exercise in futility.